# How to get number of months between dates?

Tags: java, java-time

The difference between `now` and `now + 2 months` not equal to 2 in this example, despite my thinking `LocalDate` math worked this way:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MONTHS;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 31);
            LocalDate later = now.plusMonths(2);
            
            System.out.println("Now: " + now);
            System.out.println("Later: " + later);
            System.out.println("Months between now and later: " + MONTHS.between(now, later));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Now: 2020-07-31
Later: 2020-09-30
Months between now and later: 1
```

I found this out only because I happened to run a unit test that fell on a date that breaks the expectation...

Reviewing the javadoc for LocalDate.addMonths:

> This method adds the specified amount to the months field in three
> steps:
>
> ```
> Add the input months to the month-of-year field
> Check if the resulting date would be invalid
> Adjust the day-of-month to the last valid day if necessary
> ```
>
> For example, 2007-03-31 plus one month would result in the invalid
> date 2007-04-31. Instead of returning an invalid result, the last
> valid day of the month, 2007-04-30, is selected instead.

Meaning this is working as intended. So without resorting to the *vintage* Date/Time api...

**What is the correct way to get the number of months between two dates?**

Comment: i think your method is exatly correct , the ` MONTHS.between `  annotation show:      * The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of
     * complete units between the two dates.
     * For example, the amount in months between 2012-06-15 and 2012-08-14
     * will only be one month as it is one day short of two months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to only consider years and months. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/SwULoY)</sup>

```
System.out.println(
    "Months between now and later:"  + 
    ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(
        YearMonth.from(now), 
        YearMonth.from(later)
    )
);
```

Import `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` and `java.time.YearMonth`.